# Why did mv delete a file with mv id_rsa *.old?

Tags: bash, shell, files, rename, wildcards

I wanted to backup my `~/.ssh/id_rsa` to `id_rsa.old`, and it looks like it got deleted!  How is this possible?  :)

```
root@localhost:~/.ssh# ls -l
total 16
-rw------- 1 root  root  3326 Mar 12 11:22 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root   756 Mar 12 11:22 id_rsa.pub
-rw------- 1 userx userx  666 Mar  8 11:09 known_hosts
-rw-r--r-- 1 userx userx  666 Feb 29 10:53 known_hosts.old
root@localhost:~/.ssh# mv id_rsa *.old
root@localhost:~/.ssh# ls -l
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root   756 Mar 12 11:22 id_rsa.pub
-rw------- 1 userx userx  666 Mar  8 11:09 known_hosts
-rw------- 1 root  root  3326 Mar 12 11:22 known_hosts.old
root@localhost:~/.ssh# touch p
root@localhost:~/.ssh# mv p *.p
root@localhost:~/.ssh# ls -l
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root   756 Mar 12 11:22 id_rsa.pub
-rw------- 1 userx userx  666 Mar  8 11:09 known_hosts
-rw------- 1 root  root  3326 Mar 12 11:22 known_hosts.old
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root     0 Mar 12 11:28 *.p
root@localhost:~/.ssh# rm *.p
root@localhost:~/.ssh# ls -l
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root   756 Mar 12 11:22 id_rsa.pub
-rw------- 1 userx userx  666 Mar  8 11:09 known_hosts
-rw------- 1 root  root  3326 Mar 12 11:22 known_hosts.old
userx@localhost:~$ uname -r
4.2.0-30-generic
userx@localhost:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
userx@localhost:~$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: @Scott How on Earth is *this* a duplicate of *that*?!  This question is about `move` _re_ `move`'ing a file.  The **answer** may be similar, but this is a COMPLETELY different question.

Comment: Actually, it IS a duplicate because the underlying problem is the same - you expected unix filename globs to work exactly  the same dos/windows wildcards.  They don't.   Furthermore, you don't see it as a duplicate because you're expecting to be given a single magic command that will solve your exact problem without you having to think or understand, rather than an explanation of what the problem is and generic information on how to solve it.  Another unrealistic/false expectation.

Comment: Look carefully at the filesizes.  id_rsa was 3326 and known_hosts.old was 666.  After the move, id_rsa is gone, but known_hosts.old is 3326.

Comment: @cas: "Duplicate" and "underlying problem are the same" are completely different issues. It's very possible for multiple questions to have the same underlying problem; this does not invalidate their status as independent questions. In this case, you're wrongly comparing a question from a user who understands how unix globs work but wants to do something like MSDOS wildcards with a question from a user who mistakenly thinks globs are MSDOS wildcards.

Comment: Thanks for discovering the obvious flaw in my mental circuitry - thinking that MSDOS rules apply to bash.  How silly of me :)  I will mark it as duplicate!

Comment: at least until you get used to how unix globs work, i'd suggest putting `alias mv='mv -i'` and `alias cp='cp -i'` in your `~/.bash_profile`.  you can then either logout and login again, run `. ~/.bash_profile` or run the same commands in your current shell.  Every bash shell you start from then on will have those aliases, which will cause bash to always run `mv` as `mv -i`.  `mv -i` makes `mv` prompt you for yes/no answer whenever it's about to overwrite a file. ditto for `cp -i`.

Comment: NOTE that using `find ... -exec mv` or `xargs mv` etc will run `mv` directly and bypass any aliases, as will any other program other than bash - they will all call `mv` directly.  i.e. the aliases are only active on the bash command line.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It has been renamed as `known_hosts.old`, hence has overwritten the previous contents of `known_hosts.old`.

As you already have a file named `known_hosts.old` in there so the glob pattern `*.old` has been expanded to `known_hosts.old`.

In a nutshell, the following:

```
mv id_rsa *.old
```

has been expanded to:

```
mv id_rsa known_hosts.old
```

In `bash`, if there was not a file named `known_hosts.old` present there it would expand to literal `*.old` (given you have not enabled `nullglob`).

Comment: In the output that's shown, this appears very quickly with the *filesize*.  Note that **id_rsa** had size 3326 while **known_hosts.old** had 666. After the move, **id_rsa** is gone, and **known_hosts.old** is 3326.

Answer (score 19):

It looks like you thought that `mv id_rsa *.old` would move `id_rsa` to `id_rsa.old`, with the `*` replaced by the first argument, but this is not the case. Wildcards are expanded by the shell, not by the command. By the time `mv` sees the command, the shell has expanded the wildcard. There are four cases:

- The wildcard pattern does not match any file. With most shells, this leaves the wildcard pattern unexpanded, and so `mv` is invoked with the arguments `id_rsa` and `*.old`. It then moves `id_rsa` to a file called `*.old` (with the asterisk being the first character of the file name). Some shells (depending on their configuration) will instead display an error and not run the command in that case.
- The wildcard pattern matches exactly one file which is not a directory. In this case, the shell replaces the pattern by the name of the matching file. Thus `mv` moves `id_rsa` to that matching file, overwriting the previous file. This is what happened in your case: `mv` was invoked with the arguments `id_rsa` and `known_hosts.old`, to `known_hosts.old` got overwritten.
- The wildcard pattern matches two or more files, and the last one (in lexicographic order) is not a directory. In this case, `mv` complains, because all the files except the last one are source files, and it doesn't make sense to move multiple files onto the same file.
- The wildcard pattern matches one or more file, and the last match (in lexicographic order) is a directory. The source file is moved into that directory. If there is already a file of the same name, it is overwritten. If the pattern has more than one match, this also applies to all the files matched by the pattern except the last one, since `mv` sees them as source files.

To avoid `mv` unexpectedly overwriting target files, make it prompt for confirmation. Put this in your shell initialization (e.g. `.bashrc`):

```
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'
```

To rename a file based on its existing name, `mv` alone is no help. You need to either use another tool, or arrange to provide `mv` with the full destination name. One way to do what you were trying to do is with [brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion), which lets you specify words with a common stem.

```
mv id_rsa{,.old}
```

The shell expands this to `mv` with the arguments `id_rsa` (`id_rsa` concatenated with the empty string) and `id_rsa.old` (`id_rsa` concatenated with `.old`).

To mass-rename files according to patterns, the most commonly useful tools are [`zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv) (zsh only), [`prename`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/prename.1.html) and [`mmv`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/mmv.1.html). To rename all files of the form from `id_SOMETHING` to `id_SOMETHING.old`, you can use

```
zmv 'id_*' '$f.old'
mmv 'id_*' 'id_#1.old'
prename 's/$//' id_*
```

Comment: Also `repren`...

Comment: In your last case (wildcard expands to one or more elements, the last being a directory), then wouldn't the source file _and the others that match the expansion_ be moved into the directory?

Comment: @TripeHound Indeed, I've clarified that.

Comment: ITYM most _Bourne-like_ shells; the Thomson shell, csh, tcsh, zsh, fish don't leave the pattern unexpanded as it would be a silly thing to do (something broken by the Bourne shell)

Comment: So, the Bourne shell (and bash) are singularly responsible for people saying `find . -name *.doc …` — it blows up in other shells (except for the unlucky case where the glob matches one file in the current directory).  I wonder why Bourne thought that was a good idea.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Most shells in terms of number of users (a.k.a. “bash”).

Comment: Why would using *.doc with the find command be bad and blow up non-bash?  Isn't *.doc a proper expression?

Comment: @BojanLandekić The problem is that `find . -name *.doc` in Bourne/POSIX shells means different things depending on the number of files that match the pattern `*.doc` in the current directory: if there is none, it's equivalent to `find . -name '*.doc'`; if there is exactly one, e.g. `foo.doc`, it's equivalent to `find . -name foo.doc`; and if there's more than one and no weird file names then `find` will complain of a syntax error.